How to backtrack Apache Superset Installation?
I am installing Apache superset on my local machine. On there website, there are three approaches to install,

docker compose up
docker compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up
docker compose -f docker-compose-image-tag.yml up

I have used the first two approaches first, and it returned some kind of error and aborted the installation. On the third approach, it started the installation, but later threw some kind of error. There was a weblink which took me to the error explanation (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/errors.html#error-f405). I opened the website, but faced invalid login error. Now, the problem is this whole process has taken around 24 gbs of space in my drive.
I have deleted the container, images, and the build that were created. I have also deleted the github repo I cloned for installation. Now, I want to backtrack the process so I can delete all the junk that has been installed and take valuable space in my drive. Desperately Need Suggestions Please!!!
